# maxlength property not working with javafx webview

Tags: html, javafx, java-8, maxlength, javafx-webengine

I'm developing an application using Struts2.

It works fine in Chrome/IE etc. On [JavaFX webview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) the `maxlength` property doesn't restrict the user input to the specified amount.

Sample code:

```xml
<s:textfield  name = "user_cno" 
             label = "Contact No" 
                id = "idContactNo" 
             class = "inputField" 
         maxlength = "10" />
```

I've tried changing the User Agent to the following:

- `Mozilla/5.0`
- `AppleWebKit/537.44`
- `JavaFX/8.0`
- `Safari/537.44`

but it didn't work for any of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a `WebView` bug that has been injected in Java8. There is an unassigned [open ticket](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-26411) for the same in the JavaFX developers JIRA community.

You can sign up for free and vote for the issue if you want it to be resolved asap.

Comment: thank you so much for the prompt response. have been racking my brain over this issue.